# How to set a Timage wrapmode in delphi through code?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

(Using firemonkey and xe3).
Hi i create a img.

```
  img := Timage.Create(fsbCanvas);
  with img do
    begin
      Parent:=fsbCanvas;
      position.X:=frmMainUI.CurrentMouseX;
      position.y:=frmMainUI.CurrentMouseY;
      Bitmap.LoadFromFile('1.jpg');
      Visible:=true;
    end;
```

And now i want to set its wrapmode to iwStreach.
so i add this : 
         `Timagewrapmode.iwStreach` but i get an error saying "statement expected but expression found".

Can anybody help?

Comment: Many well respected people consider with statements to be evil and with good reason. In this case it makes your code much harder to read.

Comment: @mikeSutton Noted, This is just for asking. It wont happen again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the image `WrapMode` property this way:

```
img.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.iwStretch;
```

Note, the enumeration must be fully qualified with it's type name.

This is because the compiler directive [`"$SCOPEDENUMS"`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Simple_Types#Scoped_Enumerations) is on by default in `FireMonkey` applications.

Comment: This doesnt work unless you create the constant described in my answer. But thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Do you think you could take a look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875328/how-to-create-an-indefinite-amount-of-images-while-still-being-able-to-set-their

Comment: I thought you needed a constant but you were right. This is now my accepted awnser.